# with changing props, types of another props change in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working with react and typescript. I have about 15 pages in my site that all of them are loading in same page (list-fdata-form.tsx). I can have 15Inteface because their fields are different from each other.
I have separate page for my types<types.ts>. how can I control with changing my setting (props), a Specific interface be loaded?

my list-fdata-form.tsx file:

```
interface ListDataFormType {
    automationId?: string
    setting: ListDataSubSettingType
   items: ListDataItem[]
  }
  
  const ListDataForm = ({
    automationId = '',
    items,
    setting,
    
  }: ListDataFormType) => {
    ....
  }
```

my types.ts file:

```
export interface ListDataItem {
  company_id: string
  cost_type: string
  driver_cost_type_id: string
  is_deleted: string
}
export interface LeaveItem {
  driver_leave_type_id: string
  leave_type: string
}
export interface ImportItem {
  driver_permit_type_id: string
  permit_type: string
}
...
```

Comment: can you explain more about ". how can I control with changing my setting (props), a Specific interface be loaded?"  ?

Comment: @nima, it means when user select another link, data again will be loaded in this page. so I have to load another interface. for instanc, use select 
'leave' link, so the interface for this page has to change to 'LeaveItem', how can I control this? with call diffrent api, switch among interface?